# Load package after other package with \AfterPackage

Tags: packages, koma-script, incompatibility, preamble

I want to group packages together (in the real document, I load many more packages) and want to solve the sorting of the packages with commands like `\AfterPackage` from KOMA-Script.

I am using this solution to load the package `cleveref` after the package `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{varioref} % before cleveref
\AfterPackage{hyperref}{\usepackage{cleveref}}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents\chapter{test}
\subsection{variable references using vref}
\label{sec:references:vref}
\newpage
Some text which contains a vref reference
to section \vref{sec:references:vref}.
\end{document}
```

However the reference is never found. If I load `cleveref` instead hard coded after `hyperref`

```
\usepackage{varioref} % before cleveref
%\AfterPackage{hyperref}{\usepackage{cleveref}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

everything works as expected.

Why is `\AfterPackage` not doing what I expect it to do?

Comment: I put your penultimate paragraph at the beginning of your question to provide the reader with the reason for your use of `\AfterPackage` right away; hope you don't mind.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27347/sorting-preamble-packages-thematically-while-accounting-for-compulsory-load-orde

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`hyperref` does seem to use some `\AtEndOfPackage` trickery. The normal version of `\AfterPackage` loads `cleveref` *after* `hyperref`, but *before* the trickery mentioned above. To ensure that `cleveref` is only loaded after `hyperref` has finished its business, use the "exclamation version" `\AfterPackage!{hyperref}{\usepackage{cleveref}}`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{varioref} % before cleveref
\AfterPackage!{hyperref}{\usepackage{cleveref}}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents\chapter{test}
\subsection{variable references using vref}
\label{sec:references:vref}
\newpage
Some text which contains a vref reference
to \vref{sec:references:vref}.
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Both `\AfterPackage!{hyperref}{\usepackage{cleveref}}` and `\AfterAtEndOfPackage{hyperref}{\usepackage{cleveref}}` actually don't work if you issue them *after* `\usepackage{hyperref}`. My personal `cleveref` solution which is independend of its positioning in the preamble is

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndPreamble{\usepackage{cleveref}}
```

Comment: Indeed, the `\AfterPackage!` also solves the problem. However I had the impression that `\AfterAtEndOfPackage` is even more secure.

Comment: Actually I load the package using

    \newcommand{\ExecuteAfterPackage}[2]{
      \AfterAtEndOfPackage{#1}{#2}
      \AtEndPreamble{
        \IfPackageNotLoaded{#1}{#2}
      }
    }

and load the package then with `\ExecuteAfterPackage{hyperref}{\usepackage{cleveref}}`

Comment: @lockstep: `\AtEndPreamble{\usepackage{cleveref}}` isn't a general solution, since Ben User might do `\AtEndPreamble{\usepackage{cleveref}} <something> \AtEndPreamble{\usepackage{hyperref}}`.

Answer (score 7):

It can be solved using a different command: `\AfterAtEndOfPackage`. Somehow the `\AfterPackage` variant executes the code in the context of the package which is not what I wanted. This is described in the release notes of koma script: http://www.komascript.de/release3.09 (however in german).