# Best practice on organising your preamble

Tags: best-practices, preamble

I am putting together a large document and my preamble is unwieldly and disorganised. What order does it make sense to load packages. Obviously, `hyperref` goes last, apart from things that have to go after `hyperref`. I tend to load font packages first, as they seem like a big global change. What other categories should I arrange my preamble around? Are there other cases where load order is important? Should I keep other commands close to the packages they relate to? e.g. should I keep my bibliography formatting commands near my `\usepackage{biblatex}` call?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3090/packages-that-need-to-be-included-in-a-specific-order

Comment: interesting read that is slightly related: http://markelikalderon.com/2008/07/31/keeping-your-latex-preamble-in-a-git-submodule/

Comment: Also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27347/sorting-preamble-packages-thematically-while-accounting-for-compulsory-load-orde

Answer (score 109, accepted):

If you want to see how things can get tangled in a preamble have a look at the preamble of the *Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List*. It might not be exactly spaghetti code but it can certainly be classified as code soup!

So you are right, you need to have a strategy and start working on it early in the development of your document. The tips below are from my own workflow and observations.

Early on, when I started with LaTeX, I realized that having used numerous macros and  packages to change the looks of almost every single parameter originally set by the LaTeX `book.cls`, I would have been better off  developping my own class and this is my first tip.

**1. Consider developing your own class or package to hold your changes.**

It is as simple as hitting a `save as` button to save the base class `.dtx` file and its `.ins` file. It will get you going with *literate programming* and honestly it should not take longer than an hour or two to find out how it all works. When you use `doc` for the first time you  might get disoriented, but eventually you get used to the conventions. Another advantage of this approach is that at the beginning of developing a new document, you will find out that on Mondays, Wednesdays and Thursdays, you will want your document to look one way and on the rest of the days of the week you will want it in another way. By writing your *rationale* down using literate programming, it helps you settle your ideas.

**2. Have the packages and  own related commands, near each other**

For smaller changes, i.e., write short packages, either using the doc/docstrip system or if you are in a hurry just use the package `filecontents` and write them on the fly while developing the document. This tends to remove a lot of code and comment lines in the preamble. I have all maths related macros normally in a package called `moremaths`.

```
% MATHEMATICS
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}[2000/07/18] %% Displayed equations
\let\equation\gather                          %% See tabu and hyperref docs
\let\endequation\endgather
\usepackage{amssymb}[2002/01/22] %% and additional symbols
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eucal}
```

Similarly, for tables

```
%% Tables
%%  TABLES
\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage{longtable}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{dcolumn}
\RequirePackage{multirow}
%% Set some local commands and colors
\RequirePackage{colortbl}              % for colored table cells
\definecolor{green}{rgb}{0.1,0.1,0.1}
\newcommand{\done}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}done}  %{0.9}for done tables
%
%
```

**3. Divide the preamble into headings, such as `typography`, `graphics`, `maths`, `sectioning` etc.**

If you do not develop your own class and use any of the major classes such as `Koma` or `memoir`, you will discover that in general these classes have their own configuration commands for every possible change; it helps if you divide all the relevant commands in sections. If the sections grow, i.e, if you have too many `typography` save the code in a package and name it `moretypography` or `moremaths` etc. Again here, if the preamble grows question the need for your own class.

**4. Have the problematic package settings in their own packages e.g., `sethyperef` or `setlistings` package etc.**

Some packages are difficult to set and can give you problems if they are loaded before or after some packages (See [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before)). Others need some complicated and long settings. Again here if you work on a long documents it may be worth changing these settings to small packages. If you identify sources of errors better save and restore commands rather than move them around. For example the `verse` package gave me problems with the macro `theHpoemline` and I normally only load it together with the following macros.

```
\let\oldH\theHpoemline
\let\theHpoemline\undefined
```

There are a lot of similar techniques in the *Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List*, preamble, worth a read.

Comment: About the "consider developing your own `.sty` file" comment. Then the question becomes "How to organise the `.sty` file… Since my `main.tex` is basically just preamble and then `\include{chapter1}`… etc, I don't gain anything by doing this, really.

Comment: @Seamus It helped me organize a rather huge preamble. I first started with item 3) made blocks of the preamble into small packages `moremath`, `typography`, `morelists` etc. It gave stability to at least sections of the preamble, which originally had a mix of newcommands, settings and use package. Once it settled I combined  everything into a `.dtx`. When you busy writing you tend to just put things at the bottom of the preamble rather than organize it properly. Once it is in a `.dtx` the question... how to organize it becomes easier to answer.

Comment: @Seamus Sorry for the double post to continue, in the dtx you describing what you doing, `section{typography}`, include `microtype` to minimize hyphenation and better line breaks, add csquotes..., `\def{TODO}` for short notes... hope you get the idea. Give it a try will cost you one hour:)

Comment: "code soup" that is almost "spaghetti code" should be "code minestrone".

Answer (score 44):

As you've already observed, loading `hyperref` should happen very late in the preamble. (However, if you load `cleveref`, you probably already know that it should be loaded *after* `hyperref`.) For more information on package loading orderings see, for instance, the question ["Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before)

Without knowing what your document is about, I don't believe it's possible to give very specific recommendations on how your document's preamble should be organized/structured. The following comments and notes are therefore a bit generic.

- You may want to put the entire preamble content into a `.sty` file called, say, `seamus-preamble-package`, to be loaded via `\usepackage{seamus-preamble-package}` as the one and only instruction in the main document's actual preamble. (Of course, this `.sty` file needs to be located in a directory that's searched by your TeX implementation.) If nothing else, putting the preamble stuff into a `.sty` file frees you from having to provide all those `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` instructions.
- Computer code being long and unwieldy is not the same as it being inefficient or needlessly complex. If your document is long and complex, there's probably no reason for the preamble to be simple and short. Do check, though, if there are packages that don't need to be loaded at all, if certain package are being invoked with unneeded options, or if there exist some packages that could execute some tasks currently being coded laboriously in the preamble.
- A general recommendation, which I'd say applies not only for organizing a preamble, is to use comments and whitespace liberally. That way, if you or someone else has to change stuff in the preamble at some later point in time, less time will be wasted figuring out what's going on and what may need to be changed.
- Depending on how complex the preamble is, it may make sense to write up a miniature table of contents as a "guide" to the preamble's structure. This guide could be as simple as providing a plain listing of the groups of tasks that are being taken care of in the preamble. *For instance*, this listing could consist of something like the following:

  - Define page layout in main body of text -- incl. appearance of sectioning headers, width and height of text block, line spacing, header and footer lines, position and format of page numbers
  - Select fonts and font-related features
  - Organize layout of table of contents pages
  - Organize appearance of headers in appendix
  - Organize appearance of bibliography and citation methods
  - Load packages related to math, define specialized math-related commands
  - Configure float-related matter -- incl. appearance of captions and the panoply of parameters related to float placement
  - Address all other tasks that don't fall neatly into one of the other categories. E.g., add certain words to a hyphenation exception list, load a package that lets you typeset the `euro` symbol, etc
  - Load packages related to hyper-referencing and other cross-referencing tasks
- Especially if you decide to organize the preamble along the themes outlined in the preceding bullet points, it would make sense to keep those instructions that relate to a specific task (say, creating the bibliography via `biblatex`, or setting the table of content's style via `tocloft`) close to the commands that load the packages in question.
- Another recommendation, possibly a bit more controversial: you could load those packages that can be invoked *without* setting any special options in a single `\usepackage` instruction.

  - As @MichaelPalmer observes in his comment, a variation on this method is to have a single `\usepackage` statement but to devote one line to each package being loaded. This lets the reader see clearly what's being loaded, and it also provides a method for adding short comments on each line of associated code.

Comment: re: load everything with a single `\usepackage` : I disagree. It makes it hard to replace a package, or comment out a package and things like that…

Comment: Sorry if I didn't express this clearly enough: I did not suggest to load *every* package via a single `\usepackage` statement, but only those that needn't be loaded with specific options. I'll rewrite that passage.

Comment: You can use a single `\usepackage` clause yet still put every package name into a separate line. I do this for all packages that are loaded without options.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer That's a good point.

Comment: In which order are packages in the same `\usepackage` statement loaded?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Not knowing which packages the OP actually will be loading, it's not possible to be precise here. In general, the order doesn't matter; for example, AFAICT it doesn't matter if `amsmath` is loaded before or after `amssymb`. However, if a package does have to be load after some other package, that'll usually be known to the author of the preamble instructions, won't it?

Comment: @Mico: sorry, probably my question wasn't clear enough. What I meant is: if I write `\usepackage{package1,package2}`, does `package1` always get loaded before `package2`? Or viceversa, or is it undefined/implementation-dependent?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: I believe they're loaded sequentially in the order  specified in the `\usepackage{...}` command. Looking at the `.log` file(s) generated by the main `.tex` file(s), I've never seen an exception to this. :-)

Answer (score 29):

Preambles that load a lot of packages (or large packages, such as TikZ) can really slow down your workflow. TeX supports format (.fmt) files, which store TeX data structures in serialized form. TeX can reload them and pick up where it left off in processing a given document. By creating a format file, you can avoid re-loading packages every time you build your document.

Creating a format file requires a number of steps (I'm using `pdflatex` in TeXLive 2011):

1. Move your preamble from your document (I'll call that `doc.tex`) to its own file, including the `\documentclass` declaration. Call the new file `preamble.tex`.
2. Add a definition to the bottom of `preamble.tex` that will indicate it has been loaded: `\def\preambleloaded{}`
3. Put the following line at the very beginning of `preamble.tex`: `%&pdflatex`.

   This ensures that your preamble loads the LaTeX sources. Without it, the next step will fail. `preamble.tex` should look something like this:

   ```
   %&pdflatex
   \documentclass{...}
   ... 
   \def\preambleloaded{}
   %% end of preamble.tex
   ```
4. Run `pdflatex` with the `-ini` option to dump the format file: "`pdflatex -ini preamble \dump`".
5. Add the following line to the top of `doc.tex`: `%&preamble`.

   This line ensures your preamble format file will be loaded.
6. Now we need to make sure `doc.tex` inputs `preamble.tex` if the format file does not exist. In place of all the code you moved to `preamble.tex`, add this test which only loads `preamble.tex` if `preambleloaded` has not been defined:

   ```
   \ifx\preambleloaded\undefined
      \input{preamble}
   \fi
   ```

   `\begin{document}` should immediately follow the test above. The beginning of `doc.tex` should look like:

   ```
   %&preamble
   \ifx\preambleloaded\undefined
      \input{preamble}
   \fi
   \begin{document}
   ...
   ```

After the above, you can modify `doc.tex` all you want and TeX will not re-parse `preamble.tex` when building `doc.tex`. If you change `preamble.tex`, just re-run the `pdflatex -ini` command to rebuild the format file.

This is a good place to plug [Chris Monson's LaTeX Makefile](http://code.google.com/p/latex-makefile/), which will re-make your format file as needed (i.e., `make doc` will re-build `preamble.fmt` when `preamble.tex` changes).

Comment: I tried this, but I get the following error: `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.` when I run `pdflatex -ini preamble \dump`

Comment: I had to run `pdflatex -ini preamble` and then when it got to the end and prompted me, `\dump` worked. weird.

Comment: You might also need to use the `-parse-first-line` option, or hunt down the relevant option in `texmf.cnf`.

Comment: (responding to the first comment) - maybe your shell treats `\` as special and you need to escape it?

Comment: It works if I do `pdflatex -ini "preamble.tex\dump"`.

Answer (score 19):

It's a somewhat peripheral matter, but I ordinarily comment `\usepackage` whenever I've introduced a package for the sake of some specific command or environment. I may not remember those relationships in the future, and commenting helps with debugging, as well with finding solutions that worked in the past.

Examples:

```
\usepackage{datetime}       % allows \currenttime
\usepackage{rotating}       % allows sidewaystable environment
\usepackage{dpfloat}        % allows use of leftfullpage and fullpage environments, to place successive figures on facing pages
```

Of course, specifying the purpose of a given package helps me classify it in relation to others — its function is not the same in all documents.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a detail that'll probably be trivial to most, but made me stumble one time: Put the **metadata** (`\author`, `\title`, `\date`) **towards the end** of your preamble. Packages like `titling` depend on that information (This is [where I failed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27467/4012)). You might want to put them *before* `hyperref` though, so that it can [automatically gather that data via the `pdfusetitle` option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17218/4012).

I was just used to putting it first in my preamble because these commands were among the first things I learned in LaTeX, so they stayed at the top, while other things (= packages) were added at the bottom.

Another detail that won't matter in most situations, but can nonetheless easily be done: Put [**`fontenc` *after*** all your packages loading **fonts**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2859/4012) in order to avoid loading any unnecessary T1-encoded fonts from the Computer Modern family.

Comment: You do not seem to have to place `\title` before `hyperref` for the pdfusetitle option to notice it.