# MLA Package and Thumbpdf

Tags: errors, pdf, auxiliary-files, mla-style, thumbpdf

I'm currently trying to set up a template for MLA format. There's one warning that never goes away, however:

> Package thumbpdf Warning: Thumbnail data file `Project*Name.tpt' not found.

Does anyone know what causes/how to fix this problem? Currently I have in the project folder the following files (and other associated files that come with compiling, except the .tpt file):

> Project Name.tex
>
> mla.sty
>
> thumbpdf.sty
>
> thumbpdf.tex
>
> thumbpdf.pl

I've followed the install directions for thumbpdf found here: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/thumbpdf

Or at least, I've gotten the thumbpdf.sty, .tex, and readme in the right directories in the MikTeX folder in Program Files. I'm not quite sure what to do with the .pl file.

Here is the preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\usepackage[pdftex]{thumbpdf}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{mla}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

Comment: I've never needed `thumbpdf` with my MiKTeX installation, most definitely not to fulfill MLA requirements. Any particular reason you're using it?

Comment: Also, a few remarks on your preamble: Always put [`hyperref` (almost) last](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/4012). You don't need to load `url`, which is loaded by `hyperref`, nor `ifpdf`, which is loaded by `geometry`. In general, [Best practice on organising your preamble](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40760) might be of interest to you.

Comment: Oh and btw, I am able to reproduce your error though :)

Comment: Hmm... I included thumbpdf since I thought it might resolve the warning. I see that taking it out makes no difference, though. And thanks for the link - I haven't really looked into optimizing my preamble, and I suppose I should start looking into that.

Comment: `thumbpdf.pl` is a Perl script that must be run with the main PDF file as input (most TeX distributions already have it to be simply called from the command line). But, as Heiko below is saying, there's no need for it with modern PDF viewers.

Comment: You can avoid that `mla` requests `thumbpdf` with the following magic just before `\usepackage{mla}`: `\expandafter\def\csname ver@thumbpdf.sty\endcsname{}`. Or just live with the warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to run `thumbpdf` to generate the thumbnails:

```
pdflatex ProjectName
thumbpdf ProjectName
pdflatex ProjectName
```

However, the PDF viewers are able to generate the thumbnails on the fly very fast or they do not support thumbnails at all. Therefore package `thumbpdf` is not really needed, except if you want to provide different thumbnails as the standard ones.

**Update**: You can ignore the warning or if you do not want to have embedded thumbnails and to run `thumbpdf`, then do not use the package as in the given MWE.

Additionally package loading can be disabled in LaTeX by fooling LaTeX's package management. For each package it remembers the data (date, version, info) of the optional argument of `\ProvidesPackage` under the name `\ver@<package name>.sty`. If `\ProvidesPackge` is missing the macro is defined as empty string. This macro helps LaTeX to know, if a package is already loaded. In the that case the package is not loaded again.
Also the data are used for `\listfiles`.

```
\makeatletter
\@namedef{ver@thumbpdf.sty}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{mla}
```

Comment: So, essentially ignore the warning unless I want different thumbnails?

Comment: It's the `mla` package that requires `thumbpdf`. :( Probably because it was written some years ago when PDF viewers didn't provide the thumbnails automatically and the author forgot to remove the call. It sports also a `\usepackage{times}` that reveals its age.

Comment: @egreg I have edited the answer and explain, how to disable the loading of a package.