# How to code-fold in TeX-Studio or LaTeX in general?

Tags: texstudio, code-folding

I want to fold the whole part before `\begin{document}` where it is just formatting the LaTeX document. Is there a way to do this in LaTeX, in general, or at least in TeXstudio? Could I use some `\begin{}` structure to do it?

Comment: Although code folding is possible in TeXStudio http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5281/15717, I don't think it's wise to do it. May be add the preamble (packages and custom macros) as package before `\begin{document}` follow http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40760/best-practice-on-organising-your-preamble

Comment: Cut all your preamble and save as preamble.tex, then type \input{preamble} before of \begin{document}.

Comment: In general, you code-fold by editing your LaTeX code with a text editor that supports code folding.  My choice of editor is Vim.  It also supports syntax highlighting for many languages including LaTeX.

Comment: Why not split your code in many files and then include them within a single main file? You can define the main file as Master document and when you compile any open file, the main file will be compiled.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note, code folding is a feature of an editor not a language. So there cannot be in 'code folding in LaTeX in general'.

Coming back to your intention, TeXstudio does not directly support 'folding everything before `\begin{document}`'. In TXS folding is limited to environments and structure commands (`\section`, etc.). However, you can define arbitrary folding ranges using the comments

```
%BEGIN_FOLD

%END_FOLD
```

That said, you may still consider separating the preamble to another file and `\input`-ing it as others have proposed in the comments. Personally, I favor this over folding, particularly in large projects that constist of multiple files anyway. While TXS can persistently save foling information in a session, the folding state is gone if you switch to another editor or pass the code to someone else. And then you would have to fold all the stuff again.

Comment: Is it possible to auto-fold certain environments, e.g. everything between `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}`, meaning they will be collapsed unless manually extended?

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Comment: It would certainly be a nice feature.