# Dividing preamble into smaller files

Tags: preamble

Preamble of my tex file is going to be so long, Can I divide it to some smaller and reusable files? I used `\include` but it seems that it did not include any thing.

Comment: Either use `\usepackage` (for `.sty` files) or `\input` (for other files, like `.tex`).

Comment: `\include` does not work in the preamble, because it is indented for chapters etc. See [When should I use `\input` vs. `\include`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include) for an explanation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would separate them into different `.sty` files, and include them via `\usepackage`.

### References:

- [Best practice on organising your preamble](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40760/best-practice-on-organising-your-preamble)
- [How to make a standard preamble into a package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77/how-to-make-a-standard-preamble-into-a-package)
- [Make your own .sty files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8750/make-your-own-sty-files/8752#8752)
- [Sorting preamble packages thematically while accounting for compulsory load orders](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27347/sorting-preamble-packages-thematically-while-accounting-for-compulsory-load-orde)